# How to make a css grid item larger

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I think this question has been asked multiple times, but I wasn't able to find an answer about when items are in the same `grid-row`.

I have 2 items inside a `grid`. I would like that the item on the `right` takes 2 times the space of the one on the `left`

I have the following.

Thanks

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-areas: "icon text text";
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-left {
  grid-area: icon;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item-right {
  grid-area: text;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item-left'>Left grid item: Icon I want to be small</div>
  <div class='item-right'>Right grid item: Some text I want to be larger</div>
</div>
```

Comment: define *more space*. 1px of difference can be considered as *more space*

Comment: @TemaniAfif just clarified "more space"

Comment: `grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 }
 .left {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: red; /* Just so we can see it */
 }
 .right {
  grid-column: 2 / end;
  background-color: blue; /* ^^^ */
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">Left</div>
 <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Just use three grid columns and order the elements as such.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item-left {
grid-area: icon;
grid-column: 1;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.item-right {
grid-area: text;
grid-column: 2 / end;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
<div class='container'>
<div class='item-left'>Left grid item: Icon I want to be small</div>
<div class='item-right'>Right grid item: Some text I want to be larger</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is better to provide more details in your answer about CODE